# Error when trying to install Bower package in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, bower, package-managers

I'm doing a Pluralsight course(https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/asp-dot-net-core-understanding) and in the first example the teacher tells to install the package "startboostrap-sb-admin-2", that's here: https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git

I'm trying to install it in Visual Studio 2015 like he says, but I get this error in the console:

`PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install startbootstrap-sb-admin-2#1.0.8 --force-latest --save
bower startbootstrap-sb-admin-2#1.0.8       not-cached https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git#1.0.8
bower startbootstrap-sb-admin-2#1.0.8          resolve https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git#1.0.8
bower startbootstrap-sb-admin-2#1.0.8     ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.0.8
Additional error details:
No versions found in https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git`

I never worked with Bower before, so I'm a litte lost here.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I installed bower yesterday and the step is as follow:

1. Download and install Node.js
2. Install Bower (npm install -g bower)
3. bower install vss-web-extension-sdk

Good luck for your install.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked up in the repository and saw this issue: https://github.com/ironsummitmedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/issues/1

Apparently Bower support is broken for this repo, that's why I'm getting this error.

The solution for now is to add this to my bower.json: 

`"dependencies": { "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2": "https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2.git#master" }`